# How to remove indents from HTML list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
<ol>
<li>1. This Convention shall be binding only upon those Members of the International Labour Organisation whose ratifications have been registered with the Director-General.</li>
<li>2. It shall come into force twelve months after the date on which the ratifications of two Members have been registered with the Director-General.</li>
<li>3. Thereafter, this Convention shall come into force for any Member twelve months after the date on which its ratification has been registered.</li>
</ol>
```

I have the above `HTML`. What `CSS` coding can I add above this `HTML` that will stop the text being indented by the `<li>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ox2bujd/

Answer (score 0):

```
Ol {margin:0;
      Padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean under 'text indent'? using  tag you get numbered list, and in your case you get twice numbered list. try this style to prevent list numbering

```
ol { list-style:none; }
```